# How do I solve the inequality $\frac{2x-3}{x+1}\leq 1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How do I solve the inequality $\frac{2x-3}{x+1}\leq 1$?

Here is my thought process:

$2x-3 \leq x+1$

so

$x \leq 4$

So in interval notation, this is $(-\infty,4]$ but apparently this is not correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Same comment. I don't think there is any problem with your solution.

Comment: Strange.  I'm doing this as an online homework assignment and it's telling me I'm wrong.

Comment: @LoLo: It's definitely *not* correct. You can't multiply both sides of an ineqality by a quantity whose sign you don't know. (If you multiply by a positive quantity, you should leave the inequality as it is, but if you multiply by a negative quantity, you must reverse the inequality, i.e., change $\le$ to $\ge$. Now, what is the sign of $x+1$? You don't know that in advance, so when you multiply by $x+1$, you don't know if the inequality should be kept or reversed...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\dfrac{2x-3}{x+1}\le1\iff0\ge\dfrac{2x-3}{x+1}-1=\dfrac{x-4}{x+1}$$

If $\dfrac{x-4}{x+1}=0, x-4=0$

Else $\dfrac{x-4}{x+1}<0\iff(x-4)(x+1)<0$

Now $(x-a)(x-b)<0$ with $a<b\implies a<x<b$

Comment: Thanks.  The answer is (-1,4].

Comment: Sorry I want to ask (-1,4]. does it mean not including -1 and including 4?

Comment: @RajSharma Yes.

Comment: but I can't find and <= here (x−4)(x+1)<0 ...

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what happens with inequalities if you multiply with a negative number?  Are you sure that you always multiply with something positive?

Comment: Since x could take positive or negative values, how could I ever guess to whether I need to switch the inequality signs? x is a variable so there is no way of knowing ahead of time whether it's negative or positive.

Comment: Consider using cases, that is: case 1: I multiply something positive: x>-1. Case 2: negative: x <-1. Don't forget case 3, I.e. what happens for x=-1? For that, solve the other cases first. ..

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{2x - 3}{x + 1} \le 1$

$\iff \dfrac{2x - 3}{x + 1} - 1 \le 0$

$\iff \dfrac{2x - 3}{x + 1} - \dfrac{x + 1}{x + 1} \le 0$

$\iff \dfrac{x - 4}{x + 1} \le 0$

Notice that $\dfrac{x - 4}{x + 1}$ changes sign at $x = -1$ and $x = 4$, so the possible solutions are $(-\infty, -1)$, $(-1, 4]$ and $[4, \infty)$. Take a test value from each of the three candidate solutions to substitute into the inequality. You will observe that $(-1, 4]$ is the only interval that satisfies the inequality.